# "suggest you follow" or "suggest you to follow"?

Tags: grammar

For example, is it:

> We strongly suggest you follow the official guide.

Or:

> We strongly suggest you to follow the official guide.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is correct:

> We strongly suggest you follow the official guide.

If you prefer the form of the second, you can modify it slightly to make it correct:

> We strongly advise you to follow the official guide.

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between these two verbs that mandates this grammatical difference, or some pointer to the grammar term I should be googling for answers? @john Thanks!